# Adding PyQt5 QWebEngineView widget results in QWindowsEGLStaticContext Error

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

The following error occurs on 1 of 2 Windows machines, but I can't find the difference between the PCs.

I can create a QWebEngineView widget, but as soon as the application tries to display the widget, I get the following error message:

```
QMainWindowLayout::addItem::createWindowSurface: Could not create the EGL window surface: 0x300e
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current
QMainWindowLayout::addItem::createWindowSurface: Could not create the EGL window surface: 0x300e
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current
QMainWindowLayout::addItem::createWindowSurface: Could not create the EGL window surface: 0x300e
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
```

The example below creates the error message on one machine but works fine on another. What's the difference here? Is there some OpenGL driver difference between the machines? What is happening behind the scenes?

```
import sys
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()

        self.engine = QWebEngineView()
        self.engine.setHtml('hello world')
        self.setCentralWidget(self.engine)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I comment out the `setCentralWidget` line, the application opens with no error. The creation of the QWebEngineView is not the problem, but the display of the widget causes the error.

Comment: You shouldn't add widgets to the main window layout like that. Use `self.setCentralWidget(self.engine)` instead.

Comment: Sure, just trying to get a quick example up. I'll make the edit. The error persists now matter how the widget is added.

Comment: I think it's unlikely you will get any useful answers unless you provide a lot more information about the differences between the two machines. What are the Windows versions? What are the *exact* versions of Qt, PyQt5 and OpenGL? What are the specific GPUs and graphics drivers in use? If there is a bug, it is most likely in Qt. Have you tried creating a C++ test case to see if it produces the same error?